# How can I Copy Data only if Header is "Name"?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have workbook with around 50 sheets in it, some of random sheet have Employee names in it. I want all the name to be copied in sheet 1 (A1)

Please note that data is not in table format.

I want Macro to run in all sheet and look out for Name header and paste it in sheet 1 (A1).

Please note "Name" list can be anywhere in the sheet there are no specific range so macro needs to find "Name" word and copy entire list till next blank row and past it into Sheet 1 again find "Name" word and paste it into sheet 1 below available list.

```
Private Sub Search_n_Copy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
       
    Dim rngCopy As Range, aCell As Range, bcell As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  
    strSearch = "Name"
     
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        Set rngCopy = Nothing
        Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bcell = aCell

            If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rngCopy = .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.End(xlDown).Row))
            Else
                Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.End(xlDown).Row)))
            End If

            Do
                Set aCell = .Columns(2).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bcell.Address Then Exit Do

                    If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngCopy = .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & (aCell.End(xlDown).Row))
                    Else
                        Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.End(xlDown).Row)))
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        
        End If

            '~~> I am pasting to sheet1. Change as applicable
        If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Range("B2").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "x"
        Range("A1").Select
    
    End With
```

Comment: Post your attempt and maybe we can help. Simply saying "I want a macro" should hopefully get you nowhere on SO.

Comment: You can loop on each sheet and use [`Range.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) to search for `"Employee Name"`

Comment: Thank you, I have tried but didn't work

Comment: You can search for any cell containing a "NAME" string by using [RegEx](https://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/) and [this website](https://regexr.com/) is super useful for testing your RegEx on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Range.Find` method to find all the instances of "name". The key to this is keeping track of the first one that you find so that when `Find` gets back to that cell you don't keep processing. If you don't do this, it will keep going in a circle forever. Here's an example.

```
Private Sub Search_n_Copy()

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstFound As String

    'find the first instance of name
    Set rFound = Sheet1.UsedRange.Find("name", , xlValues, xlPart)

    'continue only if you found at least one instance
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        'record the first one you found because Find loops back on itself
        sFirstFound = rFound.Address

        Do
            'copy the name to another sheet
            Sheet1.Range(rFound.Offset(1), rFound.Offset(1).End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Sheet2.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            'find the next instance of name
            Set rFound = Sheet1.UsedRange.FindNext(rFound)

        'stop looping when you get back to the first found cell
        Loop Until rFound.Address = sFirstFound
    End If

End Sub
```

If you want to do it for every sheet (and probably not the one where you're writing the results) it would look like this

```
Sub Search_n_Copy()

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstFound As String
    Dim shSrc As Worksheet
    Dim shDest As Worksheet

    'Change this to match your sheet's name
    Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")

    For Each shSrc In Worksheets
        If shSrc.Name <> shDest.Name Then
            With shSrc
                Set rFound = shSrc.UsedRange.Find("Name", , xlValues, xlPart)
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    sFirstFound = rFound.Address
                    Do
                        shSrc.Range(rFound.Offset(1), rFound.Offset(1).End(xlDown)).Copy _
                            shDest.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        Set rFound = shSrc.UsedRange.FindNext(rFound)
                    Loop Until rFound.Address = sFirstFound
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next shSrc

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, what do I need to do if I want to run this code to all sheets in the workbook.

Comment: I am getting an error while applying for each worksheet code